# How to select a specific value from drop down list in webdriver

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium and need help to figure out how to select a specific value from drop down list. Scenario is that when I click on the arrow it gives a list to select from and when I select any of the value, another filed opens up to enter value in it. So please tell me how to select value from the list by clicking on it.

Here is the HTML:

```
div class="custom-select"
<select class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" required="" ng-class="{ 'ng-fieldEmptyOnCreate' : (profileAdminTab.modalrole.$dirty || submitted) && profileAdminTab.modalrole.$error.required }" ng-options="item.Role for item in RolesData | filter: {IsSecurityRole: true} | orderBy: 'RolePriority':false" ng-change="SetAllowedPermission()" ng-model="RolesData.selectedRole" name="modalrole">
<span class="error ng-binding ng-hide" ng-show="(profileAdminTab.modalrole.$dirty || submitted) && profileAdminTab.modalrole.$error.required">Roles are required</span>
/div
/div
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the select tag not have any option tags in it?

Comment: So what have you tried? Or are you just looking for someone to write your code, with very little information to go from?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way would be to use Selenium IDE to record user actions and then interrogate the html generated to see what the elements and drop down selectable items are called.